# How to properly read string from a tuple in python?

Tags: python, hex, tuples, ascii, sensors

I am using python to read data from a sensor. the measurement are sent through UDP. I wrote a small function to read the 816 bytes messages:

```
def _recvdata(tcp, _row):
    string = ''
    bytes_read = 0
    #bytes_n = _row - bytes_read
    while bytes_read < _row:
        try:
            chunk = tcp.recvfrom(_row - bytes_read)
        except socket.timeout:
            print("Receiver timeout")
            return None
        bytes_read += len(chunk[0])
        string += chunk[0]
    print(int(chunk[0], 16))
    return chunk[0]
```

the returned tuple chunk contains the the measurement in chunk[0] and the ip address in chunk[0].
The element I'm interested in is chunk[0], but the weird probleme I have is when I print it or return it, it shows me unreadable data like this:

> ÿîP               -  7  A  K                 <     
>   ÿîc               -  7  A  K                 <             ÿîv
>   2  7  A              7                ÿî‰n  n  2           2  Z 
>   U  ‚  d  P  P  F          7       ÿî›      P  <     A  K     
>     #  #  2      #  7       ÿî®      P  <     A  K        #
>
> ## 2      #  (       ÿîÁ(  (        -    F    A
>
> <                 ÿîÔd  d  #    #  A  K  #    -  -  U  U  A
>     (  #  P  ÿîæd  #  #    #  A  K  #    -  -  U  U  A          (
>
> ## P   ÄVi   !"#$%&'()ÿîùP  ‚  ‚  K  U  A  2  d  A     2  _  _  Z     U       ÿîZ  <  <  F  7  A     7  7  2
>
> P  (  7         (  ÿî         P  s  d  K  A  U  (  -  s  s  (  d 
>   7     #  <  #  ÿî1         P  s  d  K  A  U  (  -  s  s  (  d  7
>   #

but then when I print the whole tuples chunk, the characters are shown correctly:

> '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f
>   !"#$%&\'()\xff\xee\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xee\x13\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xee&\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xee8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xeeK\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xee^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xeeq\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xee\x83\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xee\x96\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xee\xa9\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xee\xbc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xee\xce\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00v\xedt\x00\x00'

I don't know how to print the latter using chunk[0] only. I have tried:

- binascii.unhexlify
- int(chunk[0], 16)

When I type type(chunk[0]), it returns str. but then I would guess it's a sting of hex values ?
thanks for any help

Comment: Interesting. How does the actual sending of the data is being handled from the sensor?
Might i suggest attempting to connect to it using simple telnet client `telnet [ADDR] [PORT]` and then seeing if any data sent from the sesnsor makes sense.

Comment: I actually could not use telnet to read the packet. but the hex format looks more correct, in the sensor's documentation, to get a proper reading of the angle for example, they ask me the following:

exchange the 2 bytes : 0x16 0x18
get 2 bytes integer: 0x618
then transform to decimal system:1560
then multiply by 0.01 to get angle

Comment: There's actually a python module that you could try out to: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html
In particular, the `unpack` function or the `unpack_from` one.

Comment: Try `return bytes(chunk[0])`

Comment: bytes(chunk[0]) returns the same characters...

Answer (score 0):

Would `print(chunck[0].encode('utf-8'))` give you proper output?

Comment: no it will print an error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 42: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the hex representation of the characters, you should return the hex representation of a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes) object:

```
res = bytes(chunk[0]).hex()
```

Comment: Updated, you should now get a string of hex values.